# Rasterio Python not reading "pixel" values correctly

Tags: python, rasterio, sentinel-2, units, sentinelsat

I'm trying to simply get the NIR values from Sentinel2 in python. It should be as simple as

```
#import required libraries
import rasterio

band8 = rasterio.open('R10m/B08_10m.jp2', driver='JP2OpenJPEG') #nir
band8.read(1)
```

Output:

```
array([[2362, 2634, 2692, ..., 1996, 2224, 2160],
       [1932, 2250, 2540, ..., 1992, 2104, 1946],
       [1764, 1926, 2242, ..., 2052, 2010, 1708],
       ...,
       [2148, 1908, 2252, ..., 1988, 2060, 2120],
       [2032, 2464, 2728, ..., 2006, 2094, 2122],
       [1884, 2114, 2692, ..., 2034, 2106, 2066]], dtype=uint16)
```

However, NIR values (Band 8 in sentinel) should be between 0 an 1. In fact, using the SNAP tool provided, the reading is between 0 and 1. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Answered briefly in the comments!

Comment: If the datatype of the image is 16 bit integer then the assumption of range 0-1 does not make sense. Within that range there are only two integer values, zero and one. I would rather guess that SNAP is scaling data values 0-4095  https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric to range 0-1.

Comment: holy cow, i've been looking for a link like that for hours! I couldn't find any info on the measuring units, so I assumed they were wrongly read by rasterio. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @user30184 - care to make that an answer that Alex can accept

Comment: The title of the question as it stands now is misleading.

Comment: Care: the tool that @user30184 has suggested may not be appropriate. Please read the product documentation: you have to know the data you are working with. If you make wrong assumptions all the work you'll do on the data will be flawed by that mistake, so potentially unusable. Please find the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

The values in the array seem reasonable. The expected range is 0-4095.
The radiometric resolution of Sentinel MSI data is documented in https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric

> The radiometric resolution of the MSI instrument is 12 bit (1), enabling the image to be acquired over a range of 0 to 4095 potential light intensity values.

and

> The Sentinel-2 instrument acquires measurements at 12 bits. These measurements are converted to reflectances and stored as 16 bit integers in the S2 product.

If SNAP reports values within range 0-1 it is obviously scaling the data.

Answer (score 1):

Sentinel2 products, both L1C and L2A, are given as a Quantification value (10000) times the TOA/BOA radiance, respectively. To get the radiance value you must divide the DN for the quantification value, which is given in the metadata.

Read the products description page for further information: https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-1c/algorithm